# When use composite component Myfaces throws exception "Cannot cast UIpanel to panelGroup"

Tags: exception, casting, myfaces

I made some research and i found a guy who have the same problem below(Its is in portugueshttps://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javasf/OBPyBP6Sfjs)  but the site that he gave dont exist anymore  and he don't answer my email for 2 days so...

**Problem is:** whenever i use an composite component i got that exception (even if they are empty just for test):

> javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot
>   be cast to javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
>     org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   root cause
>
> java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.faces.component.UIPanel cannot be
>   cast to javax.faces.component.html.HtmlPanelGroup
>     org.apache.myfaces.shared.renderkit.html.HtmlGroupRendererBase.encodeEnd(HtmlGroupRendererBase.java:65)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlCompositeComponentRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlCompositeComponentRenderer.java:71)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
>     com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
>     org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:285)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>     com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
>     org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter.java:147)
>     org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)

For me look likes that when you use an composite, myfaces try to generate an panel and for some reason the exception is throwed, and just to remember that i made this test with the body having only the composite and composite itself is empty(with interface and implementation sections).

I am using Myfaces 2.1.11, tomcat 7(pluging for maven), jsf 2.0, hibernate.